# Mass Retag Request

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

**Remaining:**

```
[oracleclient] -> [oracle-client]

[subversion] -> [svn]

[t-sql] -> [tsql]

[oo] vs [object-oriented] vs [oop] ??

[web.config] -> [web-config] ??

[hex] vs [hexadecimal] ??
```

**Completed:**

```
[vs2008], [vs2010], etc. -> [visual-studio-2008], [visual-studio-2010]

[windows2008], [windows-2008] -> [windows-server-2008]

[gmaps] -> [google-maps]

[cpp] -> [c++]

[win-forms] -> [winforms]

[mobile-web] -> [mobileweb]

[rails] -> [ruby-on-rails]
```

Answer (score 2):

They sound good across the board.

The developers went through a great pains to get the `c++` tag working.

*"Every time someone tags a post `cpp`, somewhere a pony dies."*

Answer (score 1):

cpp, gmaps, winforms, vs20*, windows[-]20* are obvious (done)

mobile-web and mobileweb are sensible to merge, but note that the more *popular* at the moment is mobileweb (only 2 mobile-web). I've merged into mobileweb, but easy to rename.

Open to feedback on the others.

Comment: Can you ban the `cpp` tag?

Comment: Nope; that functionality is "planned", but I'm not part of the dev team so I can't influence it other than nagging.

Comment: Updated to include a couple more.

Comment: But what if I want to ask a question about the C Pre-Processor, cpp?

Comment: Then tag it preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

The tags [oo] and [object-oriented] should both go to [oop].

I vote [hex] as the tag to keep.

Comment: Object-oriented is more popular, says Google.  Consider: http://www.google.com/trends?q=oop+-alley%2C+object+oriented&ctab=0&geo=us&geor=all&date=all&sort=1

Comment: SO stats: object-oriented× 275, oo× 57, oop× 1751.  Though it brings up the usual question, do we try to match google or go with the community consensus.  Hard Choice.