# The tag synonym system allows a malicious user to permanently destroy popular tags

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tag-synonyms, exploit

Inspired by [Possible invalid merge of [cpp] into [c++]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61103/possible-invalid-merge-of-cpp-into-c).

Currently once a tag synonym is accepted by being upvoted by 3 people with 2000 or more reputation, the tag with the lowest count is **permanently deleted** and all questions tagged with it will have the tag replaced with the synonym. This cannot be undone.

Quoting waffle's post in the thread linked above:

> Fixing this mess is a real cluster.
>
> Our merge process does not have an
>   audit trail, it does a pure global
>   replace everywhere, there is no undo.

I'm extremely concerned about this. Someone can just create a couple of sock puppets account, get to 2000 reputation with each, create proposals to make all the popular tags synonyms of C# (for example c, c++, java, etc), upvote himself or herself with the sock puppet accounts, and the tags will be permanently* gone.

<sub>* Of course they can be recovered from the data dump or backups, but this will involve a lot of development time and headaches.</sub>

Comment: The merge process **MUST** and **CAN ONLY** be initiated by a moderator. Once a synonym is created it only affects the future.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just slow, but I can't even get one real account to 2000 rep, let alone several sockpuppets.  And the rep would have to come in part from legitimate upvotes; sockpuppet upvoting is checked for.

Comment: I recall complaining that synonyms not being retroactive was bad. I hereby take it back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the linked example this is only such a problem because it slipped by the mods/team when they did the actual merge - *the merge doesn't happen automatically*.

To quote waffles from a comment:

> **MODERATORS MUST PERFORM A MANUAL MERGE TO FIX THE PAST**
>   3 people can create a bad synonym, that only has an affect going forward. Then moderators look here [stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=merge](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=merge) and decide what to merge or nuke

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood how the system works! Apologies