# Merge [compilers] into [compiler]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

I think it'd be fairly reasonable to merge [compilers](/questions/tagged/compilers) (104) into [compiler](/questions/tagged/compiler) (1826).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a suggested tag synonym waiting for some votes at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/compiler/synonyms

Comment: Active synonyms are [not automatically merged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61136/the-tag-synonym-system-allows-a-malicious-user-to-permanently-destroy-popular-tag/61138#61138).

Comment: And after making this post I suggested the synonym to get things started.